# Laravel 5 send password reset and custom input name

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have register / login and send password reset on the same page.

I achieve to have register and login on the same page with different input name. But I don't find a way to add password reset input.

I want to call it "reset_email" but on my controller, if I try :

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateEmail($request);

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}

/**
 * Validate the email for the given request.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['reset_email' => 'required|email']);
}
```

I've got this error :

> We can't find a user with that e-mail address.

Any idea how to use reset_email instead of email for my input name ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your method like this:

```
...
$response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
    ['email' => $request->get('reset_email')]
);
...
```

This will get your input value and will send it to the password broker with key **email**, so it will look for users by this column.